# Unable to generate HTML report using reportNG in Maven

Tags: maven, reportng

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0          
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.operations.dashboard</groupId>
<artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DashboardAutomationProject</name>
<description>This automates the dashboard application</description>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>2.39.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
     <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
     <version>6.8.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
     <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
     <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
     <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <properties>
              <property>
                 <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                 <value>false</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                 <name>listener</name>
                 <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
              </property>
           </properties>
           <suitexmlfiles>
              <suitexmlfile>testng.xml</suitexmlfile>
           </suitexmlfiles>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
  <plugins>
     <!--TestNG-xslt related configuration.-->
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
        <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <!--Output directory for the testng xslt report-->
           <outputdir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputdir>
           <sorttestcaselinks>true</sorttestcaselinks>
           <testdetailsfilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testdetailsfilter>
           <showruntimetotals>true</showruntimetotals>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
     <id>reporty-ng</id>
     <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Hi all,

I have created a Maven Project for automating a webportal and have the above POM.xml wherein I have added all the dependencies for TestNG and ReportNG.

But I'am unable to create a ReportNG report.
Generally there should be a HTML folder created inside the test-output folder which gives a HTML report in the eclipse browser.

Can somebody help me out? Not sure what is going wrong here    enter code here

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is still useful.  ReportNG, as of 1.1.4 needs a dependency on `com.google.inject:guice:3.0`.